# Problem in receiving apple push notification

Tags: push-notification

I have written provider part in java. Notification is sent to the APNs. Not getting any exceptions. iPhone app is registered and checked the settings in the iPhone it is fine. But notification is not received by the iPhone. I don't know why? I have a doubt in notification message. But i dont know how to check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get everything just right or the push notifications will fail silently.  Here are a few things you can check:

-Have you installed your application on a real test device, and has your app successfully registered with the Apple APNS servers (I think you've said it is registered)?  If there isn't a device to send to then your notifications will get dropped.

-Are you using Development or Distribution certs and profiles?  Development MUST send notifications to the Apple sandbox servers, Distribution MUST use the Apple production servers.

-You must turn on APNS in your App ID on the Apple Portal BEFORE you create the provisioning profile.  Otherwise it misses out the  setting in the provisioning profile (which must contain sandbox or production as per my previous point).

-Does your app ID in your Info.plist exactly match the app ID on the Apple Portal?  You need it to be com.domain.appname WITHOUT the unique ID thing that Apple creates for you.

You should be able to run tcpdump or Wireshark to catch the JSON data you are sending to Apple.  If you post that then somebody might be able to notice if there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just spend a half day of finding the problem why my app doesnt receive push-notifications.
The problem was, that the time-settings where wrong.

My Hint: Check the time-settings of your device.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on what you mean by "time-settings" were wrong?

Comment: Yes, a more descriptive explanation would certainly help